# Subquery in where clause with CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, subquery, criteria-api

Can anybody give me some hints on how to put that kind of subquery in a `CriteriaQuery`? (I'm using *JPA 2.0* - *Hibernate 4.x*)

`SELECT a, b, c FROM tableA WHERE a = (SELECT d FROM tableB WHERE tableB.id = 3)` - the second select will always get a single result or null.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like the following example to create a subquery:

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root tableA = cq.from(TableA.class);

Subquery<String> sq = cq.subquery(TableB.class);
Root tableB = cq.from(TableB.class);
sq.select(tableB.get("d"));
sq.where(cb.equal(tableB.get("id"), 3));

cq.multiselect(
    cb.get("a"),
    cb.get("b"),
    cb.get("c"));
cq.where(cb.equal(tableA.get("a"), sq));
List<Object[]> = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Note the code has not been tested due to the lack of an IDE nearby.

Comment: I think that I specified that my where clause will always return one result.

Comment: Edited the question. If you need some other details, ask me please. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect the query to do in case of a `null`-case?

Comment: Return `null` (there is no null value for `a` field).

Comment: @artaxerxe Edited accordingly to the given example.

Comment: Don't you have to write `Root tableB = sq.from(TableB.class)` instead of `Root tableB = cq.from(TableB.class)` [line 5, `sq` instead of `cq`] ?

Comment: That's Great @
 
Aquillo

Comment: Subquery<String> sq = cq.subquery(TableB.class) fails with a type error. "Incompatible types. Found: 'javax.persistence.criteria.Subquery<TableB>', required: 'javax.persistence.criteria.Subquery<java.lang.String>'". I think that line should read Subquery<String> sq = cq.subquery(String). Then it all should compile and work (if you also use the correction from Unda above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DetachedCriteria` to represend the sub-query. Your code should look something like:

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TableB.class);
subCriteria.add(Property.forName("id").eq(3)); //WHERE tableB.id = 3
subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("d")); // SELECT d from

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(getPersistentClass());
criteria.add(Property.forName("a").eq(subCriteria)); //a = (sub-query)
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("a"); //SELECT a
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("b"); //SELECT b
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("c"); //SELECT c
return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

Comment: Is your code *JPA* compliant? What does `getHibernateTemplate()` mean?

Comment: Yes, is JPA comliant. getHibernateTemplate() works as a wrapper over hibernate session. This takes care of opening/closing session (all BolierPlate code) as well as it is thread safe. It also exposes methods of session and query criteria like save, update, etc.

Comment: Ok. If I change the *JPA* implementation I think I won't be able to run that code (as long as it is specific to hibernate). I would like to have a *JPA* based solution. Anyway, your solution responds to my needs I think when you rely on *Hibernate*. Thanks.